# CoordinatorLayout ignores margins for views with anchor

Tags: android, android-support-library, androiddesignsupport

Given I'm using a layout like this:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    android:id="@+id/main_content"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/flexible_space_image_height"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="64dp"
            app:expandedTitleMarginStart="48dp"
            app:statusBarScrim="@android:color/transparent"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
                />

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/mainView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        />

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:layout_width="70dp"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        app:fabSize="normal"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/appbar"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|center_horizontal"
        />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Which is pretty much the standard [Cheesesquare](https://github.com/chrisbanes/cheesesquare) sample - except the FloatingActionButton, which I would like to move up by about 20dp.

However, this will not work. No matter if I use margin, padding etc - the button will always be centered at the edge of the anchor, like this:

[image: FAB will ignore the margin]

How can I move the FAB up by 20dp as intended?

Comment: Reported at https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=176096

Comment: In what API version does the bug happen?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As there might be [bugs](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/list?can=2&q=CoordinatorLayout&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20Stars&cells=tiles) in the design-support-lib concerning the `CoordinatorLayout` & margins, I wrote a `FrameLayout` that implements/copies the same "Behavior" like the FAB and allows to set a `padding` to simulate the effect:

Be sure to put it in the `android.support.design.widget` package as it needs to access some package-scoped classes.

```
/*
 * Copyright (C) 2015 The Android Open Source Project
 *
 * Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
 * you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
 * You may obtain a copy of the License at
 *
 *      http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
 *
 * Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
 * distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
 * WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
 * See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
 * limitations under the License.
 */

import android.annotation.TargetApi;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Rect;
import android.os.Build;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewCompat;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPropertyAnimatorListener;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.animation.Animation;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;

import com.company.android.R;

import java.util.List;

@CoordinatorLayout.DefaultBehavior(FrameLayoutWithBehavior.Behavior.class)
public class FrameLayoutWithBehavior extends FrameLayout {
    public FrameLayoutWithBehavior(final Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public FrameLayoutWithBehavior(final Context context, final AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public FrameLayoutWithBehavior(final Context context, final AttributeSet attrs, final int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    }

    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
    public FrameLayoutWithBehavior(final Context context, final AttributeSet attrs, final int defStyleAttr, final int defStyleRes) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes);
    }

    public static class Behavior extends android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.Behavior<FrameLayoutWithBehavior> {
        private static final boolean SNACKBAR_BEHAVIOR_ENABLED;
        private Rect mTmpRect;
        private boolean mIsAnimatingOut;
        private float mTranslationY;

        public Behavior() {
        }

        @Override
        public boolean layoutDependsOn(CoordinatorLayout parent, FrameLayoutWithBehavior child, View dependency) {
            return SNACKBAR_BEHAVIOR_ENABLED && dependency instanceof Snackbar.SnackbarLayout;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onDependentViewChanged(CoordinatorLayout parent, FrameLayoutWithBehavior child, View dependency) {
            if (dependency instanceof Snackbar.SnackbarLayout) {
                this.updateFabTranslationForSnackbar(parent, child, dependency);
            } else if (dependency instanceof AppBarLayout) {
                AppBarLayout appBarLayout = (AppBarLayout) dependency;
                if (this.mTmpRect == null) {
                    this.mTmpRect = new Rect();
                }

                Rect rect = this.mTmpRect;
                ViewGroupUtils.getDescendantRect(parent, dependency, rect);
                if (rect.bottom <= appBarLayout.getMinimumHeightForVisibleOverlappingContent()) {
                    if (!this.mIsAnimatingOut && child.getVisibility() == VISIBLE) {
                        this.animateOut(child);
                    }
                } else if (child.getVisibility() != VISIBLE) {
                    this.animateIn(child);
                }
            }

            return false;
        }

        private void updateFabTranslationForSnackbar(CoordinatorLayout parent, FrameLayoutWithBehavior fab, View snackbar) {
            float translationY = this.getFabTranslationYForSnackbar(parent, fab);
            if (translationY != this.mTranslationY) {
                ViewCompat.animate(fab)
                          .cancel();
                if (Math.abs(translationY - this.mTranslationY) == (float) snackbar.getHeight()) {
                    ViewCompat.animate(fab)
                              .translationY(translationY)
                              .setInterpolator(AnimationUtils.FAST_OUT_SLOW_IN_INTERPOLATOR)
                              .setListener((ViewPropertyAnimatorListener) null);
                } else {
                    ViewCompat.setTranslationY(fab, translationY);
                }

                this.mTranslationY = translationY;
            }

        }

        private float getFabTranslationYForSnackbar(CoordinatorLayout parent, FrameLayoutWithBehavior fab) {
            float minOffset = 0.0F;
            List dependencies = parent.getDependencies(fab);
            int i = 0;

            for (int z = dependencies.size(); i < z; ++i) {
                View view = (View) dependencies.get(i);
                if (view instanceof Snackbar.SnackbarLayout && parent.doViewsOverlap(fab, view)) {
                    minOffset = Math.min(minOffset, ViewCompat.getTranslationY(view) - (float) view.getHeight());
                }
            }

            return minOffset;
        }

        private void animateIn(FrameLayoutWithBehavior button) {
            button.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH) {
                ViewCompat.animate(button)
                          .scaleX(1.0F)
                          .scaleY(1.0F)
                          .alpha(1.0F)
                          .setInterpolator(AnimationUtils.FAST_OUT_SLOW_IN_INTERPOLATOR)
                          .withLayer()
                          .setListener((ViewPropertyAnimatorListener) null)
                          .start();
            } else {
                Animation anim = android.view.animation.AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(button.getContext(), R.anim.fab_in);
                anim.setDuration(200L);
                anim.setInterpolator(AnimationUtils.FAST_OUT_SLOW_IN_INTERPOLATOR);
                button.startAnimation(anim);
            }

        }

        private void animateOut(final FrameLayoutWithBehavior button) {
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH) {
                ViewCompat.animate(button)
                          .scaleX(0.0F)
                          .scaleY(0.0F)
                          .alpha(0.0F)
                          .setInterpolator(AnimationUtils.FAST_OUT_SLOW_IN_INTERPOLATOR)
                          .withLayer()
                          .setListener(new ViewPropertyAnimatorListener() {
                              public void onAnimationStart(View view) {
                                  Behavior.this.mIsAnimatingOut = true;
                              }

                              public void onAnimationCancel(View view) {
                                  Behavior.this.mIsAnimatingOut = false;
                              }

                              public void onAnimationEnd(View view) {
                                  Behavior.this.mIsAnimatingOut = false;
                                  view.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                              }
                          })
                          .start();
            } else {
                Animation anim = android.view.animation.AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(button.getContext(), R.anim.fab_out);
                anim.setInterpolator(AnimationUtils.FAST_OUT_SLOW_IN_INTERPOLATOR);
                anim.setDuration(200L);
                anim.setAnimationListener(new AnimationUtils.AnimationListenerAdapter() {
                    public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
                        Behavior.this.mIsAnimatingOut = true;
                    }

                    public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
                        Behavior.this.mIsAnimatingOut = false;
                        button.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    }
                });
                button.startAnimation(anim);
            }

        }

        static {
            SNACKBAR_BEHAVIOR_ENABLED = Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 37):

I suggest an elegant solution for you:

```
<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    ...
    android:translationY="-20dp"
    ...
/>
```

Comment: considering the overall layout performance, this should be marked as solution. Don't use unnecessary linear layouts

Comment: this blows my mind! so simple and never before I used a translation in a layout! will definitely help me in other tricky situations

Comment: translationY may make view miss receiving touch event

Answer (score 14):

Try putting it in a linear layout that have padding:

```
<LinearLayout
  width=".."
  height=".."
  paddingBottom="20dp"
  app:layout_anchor="@id/appbar"
  app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|center_horizontal">

  <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:layout_width="70dp"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        app:fabSize="normal" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks. Nice try, BUT: LinearLayout does not declare an `@DefaultBehavior` which in will then disable the interaction with the parent `CoordinatorLayout`. For the FAB, I'm sure you have seen the cheese square demo: It will animateOut, once the scrolling threshold is reached. I still want that feature, just with a bit extra bottom margin.

Comment: what about padding instead of margin for FloatingActionButton.

Comment: Tried that without success. It is almost as if margins and paddings are completely ignored, once the behavior is set.

Answer (score 3):

Easy workaround is to anchor a random layout to where FAB was anchored, give it specific margin, and then anchor FAB to random layout, like this

```
<LinearLayout
 android:orientation="horizontal"
 android:id="@+id/fab_layout"
 android:layout_width="5dp"
 android:layout_height="5dp"
 android:layout_marginRight="80dp"
 android:layout_marginEnd="80dp"
 app:layout_anchor="@id/collapsing_toolbar"
 app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|end"/>

<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
    android:src="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_map"
    app:layout_anchor="@id/fab_layout"
    app:elevation="6dp"
    app:pressedTranslationZ="12dp"
 />
```

Answer (score 1):

To anchor the `FloatingActionButton` below the `AppBar` like this:
[image: Fab as anchor to the AppBar]

Extend the `FloatingActionButton` and override `offsetTopAndBottom`:

```
public class OffsetFloatingActionButton extends FloatingActionButton
{
    public OffsetFloatingActionButton(Context context)
    {
        this(context, null);
    }

    public OffsetFloatingActionButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs)
    {
        this(context, attrs, 0);
    }

    public OffsetFloatingActionButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr)
    {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int left, int top, int right, int bottom)
    {
        super.onLayout(changed, left, top, right, bottom);
        ViewCompat.offsetTopAndBottom(this, 0);
    }

    @Override
    public void offsetTopAndBottom(int offset)
    {
        super.offsetTopAndBottom((int) (offset + (getHeight() * 0.5f)));
    }
}
```

Comment: This works in the sense that it offsets the fab with respect to the seam, but it  breaks the hide/show animation, which isn't aware of the offset.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get around this issue by using both `layout_anchor` `layout_anchorGravity` along with some padding.. The anchor attribute allows you to have a `View` position itself relative to another view. However, it doesn't exactly work in the same way that `RelativeLayout` does. More on that to follow.

`layout_anchor` specifies which `View` your desired `View` should be positioned (i.e., this `View` should be placed relative to the `View` specified by the `layout_anchor` attribute). Then, `layout_anchorGravity` specifies which side of the relative `View` the current `View` will be positioned, using the typical [Gravity](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Gravity) values (`top`, `bottom`, `center_horizontal`, etc.).

The issue with using just these two attributes alone is that the *center* of the `View` with the anchors will be placed relative to the other `View`. For example, if you specify a `FloatingActionButton` to be anchored to the bottom of a `TextView`, what really ends up happening is that the the *center* of the FAB is placed along the bottom edge of the `TextView`.

To get around this issue, I applied some padding to the FAB, enough such that the top edge of the FAB was touching the bottom edge of the `TextView`:

```
<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_anchor="@id/your_buttons_id_here"
    android:layout_anchorGravity="bottom"
    android:paddingTop=16dp" />
```

You might have to increase the padding to get the desired effect. Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

I used `app:useCompatPadding="true"` with FAB and everything worked.